# LVP and Glue instead of Floating

Tags: flooring, vinyl

I have a customer who is insisting that floating floors are not reliable, stable etc. I have not glued down a Vinyl floor in a really long time. I generally work with Marble, Stone and Tile but occasionally, lately, it's been all Vinyl. Does anyone have a recommendation on which LVP to use and just as important, are there any that are just NOT a good choice for adhesive?

Sub-questions: any particularly loved glue? I am guessing it is dependent on which Vinyl Planking is picked and what its backing is made from, huh?

Comment: Think there two types.  One is floating and one is made to be glued down(not floating).  Probably gluing down the floating type will undo the warranty.

Comment: right! I hadn't considered that. Maybe that'll be my approach for not gluing it. I am not a fan....I'd rather be laying stone but if it has to be Vinyl just let me float it and be done with it. They also JUST added new decorative 4" base and he neither wants that gently pulled and put back after I install the floor or 1/4" round used. I told him there was going to caulk used somewhere then...there's a million rips. End cuts no biggie, I can get those exact. The rips will be.....close :)

Comment: Sometimes it's better to decline the job if the customer insists on doing it wrong.

Comment: I appreciate that....I'm starving or I'd just pass. Thank you though

Comment: gluing is big mistake, but if you must glue, certainly don't glue them in the dead of winter when everything is maximally shrunk: it will buckle like crazy in july. Like wise if you glue in july, it will pull apart in winter. your best bet is late spring or late fall.